# Jquery - Toggle class if only first instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggleclass

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SBAE8/

Here's my problem. I have a series of 3 items, the top most item is preceded by a headline whose visibility has been toggled by the script.  If the user deletes item 1, then the headline for item 2 appears and then if item 2 is deleted then the headline for item 3 appears.  The issue is - if they delete item 2 first, the headline for item 3 appears and I only want one headline for each set at anytime, and it should always be the first item's headline no matter which item is at the top. I've tried several methods of checking if the deleted item has a higher sibling but I cannot seem to figure this one out.

The jQuery (also see fiddle linked above):

```
    $(".doDelete").click(function () {
        var $el = $(this).closest("div.payload-container");
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        // Alert callback (removed from this example)
            // Success
                $el.next("div.payload-container").find(".headline").toggleClass("hide");
                $el.slideUp(200, function () {
                    $el.remove();
                });
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check whether there are any other headlines visible (or will be visible) first.

I check in the callback:

```
if (!$(".headline:visible").length) {
    $el.next("div.payload-container").find(".headline").toggleClass("hide");
}
$el.remove();
```

This doesn't show the next headline until *after* the `slideUp` has completed.  If that's no good, then you have to check whether it's `$el`'s `.headline` that is visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/SBAE8/1/

**Update**: Final working version http://jsfiddle.net/uE5Ap/2/

Comment: You don't seem to be using my JS there

Comment: I just realized, sorry.. something isn't working when I place into my existing code. I'm debugging..

Comment: Good thinking on your answer, only issue is when I introduce multiple sets another problem comes to light. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uE5Ap/  Try to delete any item #1 and the headline disappears.  Thanks!

Comment: @BD_Design no problem, just use a more specific selector for `:visible`: http://jsfiddle.net/uE5Ap/1/

Comment: Thanks again, now item #2 has an issue, when deleted two headlines appear in a set.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand

Comment: On your latest example (jsfiddle.net/uE5Ap/1) if you delete item #2 in any list, headline #3 appears, it shouldn't because headline #1 is already visible. There should only be one visible headline for each set. Does that clarify? Thanks, I owe you a beer!

Comment: I was using the wrong "outer" selector: http://jsfiddle.net/uE5Ap/2/ -- I'll take a blueberry sea dog

Comment: Thanks, now all is working correctly. Never heard of sea dog brewery before, but just checked out their website, I'll have to see if our local beer shop carries it - thanks for the tip! Cheers!